# nodejs: jquery ajax 302 handling

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

I am trying to use jquery in node environment. 
For normal requests ajax is functional, but with server redirections  i am facing some problem.

I know that browser handles redirects(handling 302), but here in node env, I atleast expect ajax callback to be called.

No callback( done, fail, always) is getting called for the redirected request.

Other modules like request or express can be used for my purpose. I am just curious to know what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems CORS has to be enabled explicitly like ***'jQuery.support.cors = true'*** and need to XMLHttpRequest obect to jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;    
jQuery.ajaxSettings.xhr = function () {
  return new XMLHttpRequest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery.ajax has `complete` callback.
It's type is:

```
function(jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus)
```

Chech `textStatus` or `jqXHR.status == 302` and do what you need.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: Yeah I Know that.. That is not getting called by jquery.